# Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Умный просто говорит о сложном, глупый – сложно о простом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая часть здесь - неполное предложение, поэтому на месте пропуска сказуемого при наличии паузы ставится тире.